# Send bytes32 data to a smart contract using python

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, brownie

How to send data to a function which takes `bytes32` as the input parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a function inside a smart contract like this

```js
function setStorage(bytes32 memory _value) public {
        return _value;
    }
```

And you want to call the function using `brownie`. You can simply do this

```py
# deploy or load the contract 
contract = Contract.at("0x....1236hd65d")

# call the fn.
contract.setStorage(b"Data you want to send".hex(), {"from": account})

# you can also do this
contract.setStorage("Data you want to send".encode().hex(), {"from": account})
```

- So basically you have to first encode the data into bytes & then send it as a hexadecimal value.